# Multiple Linear Regression with constraints on coefficients

Tags: python, scikit-learn, constraints, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to implement multiple linear regression using the

> [**sklearn**.linear_model.**LinearRegression**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) function.

The equation for regression is:

y = c + a<sub>1</sub>x<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub>x<sub>2</sub>

with an additional condition that:

- c always takes a value between (1,10)
- a<sub>1</sub> takes values between (0,1).

How can I principally solve such equations using Python?

Comment: Please, give us more context about your problem and data, as your question is quite general.

Comment: @sentence please see my answer to this question, which us an example bounded 3D surface fitter. I personally found the problem statement sufficient to make answer without user data.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Thank you for providing an example. Still, I do not see how your answer fullfils the need (otherwise the question is quite general, indeed) of using sklearn.

Comment: @sentence please re-read the actual question that was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example bounded graphical 3D surface fitter in Python using your equation and bounds on c with 3D scatter plot, 3D surface plot, and contour plot. You should be able to click-drag with the mouse and rotate the 3D plots in 3-space for examination. You can of course change or add bounds as you see fit.

Note that this example is using scipy's curve_fit() which allows bounds on the fitted parameters, and that the estimated initial parameters must be within the bounds so that curve_fit() can begin. In this example, the fitted parameter values for a1, a2, and c are:

fitted parameters [  9.71206053e-01   3.57603742e-02   1.63260453e-16]

with parameter "c" effectively at the lower bound of zero. If you remove the bounds from the call to curve_fit() then parameter "c" will be negative in this example.

[image: scatter]

[image: surface]

[image: contour]

```
import numpy, scipy, scipy.optimize
import matplotlib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import  Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm # to colormap 3D surfaces from blue to red
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

graphWidth = 800 # units are pixels
graphHeight = 600 # units are pixels

# 3D contour plot lines
numberOfContourLines = 16


def SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data) # show data along with plotted surface

    axes.set_title('Surface Plot (click-drag with mouse)') # add a title for surface plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data') # Z axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else there can be memory and process problems


def ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), 20)
    yModel = numpy.linspace(min(y_data), max(y_data), 20)
    X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(xModel, yModel)

    Z = func(numpy.array([X, Y]), *fittedParameters)

    axes.plot(x_data, y_data, 'o')

    axes.set_title('Contour Plot') # add a title for contour plot
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    CS = matplotlib.pyplot.contour(X, Y, Z, numberOfContourLines, colors='k')
    matplotlib.pyplot.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10) # labels for contours

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else there can be memory and process problems


def ScatterPlot(data):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)

    matplotlib.pyplot.grid(True)
    axes = Axes3D(f)
    x_data = data[0]
    y_data = data[1]
    z_data = data[2]

    axes.scatter(x_data, y_data, z_data)

    axes.set_title('Scatter Plot (click-drag with mouse)')
    axes.set_xlabel('X Data')
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data')
    axes.set_zlabel('Z Data')

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot or else there can be memory and process problems


def func(data, a1, a2, c):
    x1 = data[0]
    x2 = data[1]
    return c + (a1 * x1) + (x2 * a2)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xData = numpy.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0])
    yData = numpy.array([11.0, 12.1, 13.0, 14.1, 15.0, 16.1, 17.0, 18.1, 90.0])
    zData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.0, 12.0])

    data = [xData, yData, zData]

    # initial parameter estimates must be within bounds
    initialParameters = [1.0, 1.0, 0.5]

    # bounds on parameters - initial parameters must be within these
    # note that +/- infinity means "no bound" on that parameter
    lowerBounds = (-numpy.Inf, -numpy.Inf, 0.0)
    upperBounds = (numpy.Inf, numpy.Inf, 1.0)
    parameterBounds = [lowerBounds, upperBounds]

    # now call curve_fit passing in parameter bounds
    fittedParameters, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(func, [xData, yData], zData, p0 = initialParameters, bounds = parameterBounds)

    ScatterPlot(data)
    SurfacePlot(func, data, fittedParameters)
    ContourPlot(func, data, fittedParameters)

    print('fitted parameters', fittedParameters)

    modelPredictions = func(data, *fittedParameters) 

    absError = modelPredictions - zData

    SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
    MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
    RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
    Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(zData))
    print('RMSE:', RMSE)
    print('R-squared:', Rsquared)
```