# Bounding a parameter in a python regression model

Tags: python, regression

I am trying to set up a fairly basic regression model. I have a time series with one of the coefficients (parameters) needing to be in a given range. Is there a way to force this linear regression model to select a parameter within the known range? The code I have listed below has 3 features in X_train with only one of them requiring a bounded parameter.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
linear = linear_model.LinearRegression()
linear.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

If there is another python regression model that you would suggest using instead of this one, I am fully open to that as well. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Linear Regression with constraints on coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542827/multiple-linear-regression-with-constraints-on-coefficients)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not ideal, but as far as I know, there is no pre-canned way of doing this in Python. Some ideas on how to tackle this can be found in the posts below.

[Least Square](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36411603/limit-bounds-of-tuning-parameters-for-linear-regression-in-scikit-learn-or-stats)

[Curve Fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542827/multiple-linear-regression-with-constraints-on-coefficients)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).